# Vercel Output Source did not serve Public folder dir

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, vite, vercel

I am using React in this project with Vite.

I have two assets folders inside the Public folder

- Images
- Icons

When I run the build command `vite build` the dist includes the images and icons folders from the Puclic and it works fine.

[Build Files Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7dSC.png)

Here is my `vite.config.ts`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          let extType = assetInfo.name.split('.')[1]
          if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(extType)) {
            extType = 'img'
          }
          return `assets/${extType}/[name]-[hash][extname]`
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

But in Vercel when I depoly the page the Images and icons are not found **404**.

In Vercel I can see that the Output Source shows a second assests file that I can't access instead of the images and icons folders.

[Vercel Output Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CED5L.png)

Is this a problem in the build command in Vercel? or do I need to change the build options in `vite.config.ts` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to **Vercel Support** and they helped me figure out the problem which was an easy fix.

Vercel is case sensitive on folders names so If you have a Public folder it should be lowercase.

Correct

- **public** ✅

Wrong:

- **Public** ❌

Git might not detect file changes when you rename a folder from uppercase to lower case so I used this git config command to detect the changes

`git config core.ignorecase false`